# Why does href="/../subpage/doc.html" work?

Tags: html, url, path

The website I found looks like the following:
current URL: `http://www.example.com/stocking/`
a link: `<a href="/../shop/alphabetic/page">`

this takes you to `http://www.example.com/shop/alphabetic/page`.

From what I understand about relative paths, you use a leading slash to refer to the current base URL and leading points to go from the current directory. Therefore, it should make no sense to do the above.
Actually, I'm surprised this is even working and somehow equivalent to either

`href="../shop/alphabetic/page"`
`href="/shop/alphabetic/page"`

which should work as well for this purpose.

So how does this even work?

Comment: `a href="/"` ->root `../` cannot go heigher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` starts an absolute path.

`../` then goes up a path segment, but as you are at the top already, it has no effect and is ignored.

Comment: shouldn't it be best practice to avoid expressions that are being ignored and use one of the other examples then?

Comment: @JustinP. —Yes.